# Schedule threades while maintaining synchronaization - java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, simulator, timing

**TLDR** I'm having an hard time synchronizing multi-threaded system.

I Have implemented a *Multi-threaded*, shared-taxi simulator (with adjustable speed) that contains a *weighted graph* (where the weights are the time in milliseconds it takes to cross an edge) that represents a road map, and *users* `Taxi` and `Passenger` (each contains location and starting time).

The operation of the simulator is created by the following threads:

1. `EventManager`: initiates real-time activities (taxi and passenger) according to their starting time.
2. `MatchMaker`: runs a matching algorithm between taxis and passengers.
3. `Taxi`s: each taxi runs on a separate thread that calculates the current location of the taxi, pickup order, and searches for shortest paths.

The problem is that over time, time differences between different threads are accumulating, which in turn causes the simulator to be inaccurate.
For example, a `Taxi` may be in a location that should have taken x time to get to, while the simulator's time is at y ( y >> x ).
My guess is that the time differences may be the result of CPU timing or delays in the movement of the taxi caused by long calculations and concurrency-related methods (e.g., `wait()` and `synchronized()`).

How can I make sure all of the threads work at the same rate?
Should I add a delay to get them to synchronize?
Or maybe add a `Timer` somewhere?

---

And for the implementation of the main components (I've removed irrelevant parts to keep the question clean) of some of the threads:

To move a `Taxi` I'm iterating over it's path, and calling `sleep()` with the weight of the edge (divided by the simulator's speed to make the entier system work at the same rate) in each iteration:

```java
List<Edge> path;

@Override
public void run(){
        Iterator<Edge> itr = path.iterator();
        
        while(itr.hasNext()){
                currEdge = itr.next();
                sleep(currEdge.getWeight());
        }
}

private void sleep(long ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime / Simulator.getSpeed());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And the `EventManager` is timing new events by sleep between the event's time-stamps:

```java
Queue<Users> events;

@Override
public void run(){
        User nextEvent;
        
        while(!events.isEmpty()){
                nextEvent = events.poll();
                simulator.start(nextEvent);
                
                sleep(nextEvent);
        }
}

private void sleep(User curr) {
        if(!events.isEmpty()){
                long timeToNextEvent = events.peek().getStartTimeInMS() - curr.getStartTimeInMS();
                try {
                        Thread.sleep(timeToNextEvent / Simulator.getSpeed());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you tracking the time of the actors (taxis) purely by Thread.sleeping the desired amount? This will not work, because Thread.sleep does not guarantee that the thread sleeps for the exact requested amount. See e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Comment: I know that the CPU time does not split 100% equal and fair, but isn't it close to fair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answer makes sense, but if your problem can be modeled as a [Discrete Event Simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-event_simulation) (DES), I would advise you to use a simulated system clock. I have used and also built a couple of DES systems, and in all of them the simulated time was maintained by a queue where the elements  were sorted according to the event time. Real time between two events were of course instantaneous.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll look into it. Do you have a recommended Library for DES or did you only built them yourself?

Comment: Sorry, long time ago. My first encounter was [SIMULA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) and later C or C++. I'm sure there are quite a few of them in Java, but I have no experience of them.